# Main character reincarnated in a forest and fights a giant ant-like creature, saved by a mysterious girl

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

From the plot I remember the main character getting reincarnated in a forest. While he fights with some kind of giant ant-like creature he gets saved by a mysterious knight-like girl. So she sleeps with him to save this refugee village because of his unique over-powered system abilities. I remember her being a former princess or something of the sort

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like a misremembering of ***[Isekai Apocalypse Mynoghra - The Conquest of the World Starts With the Civilization of Ruin](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=170140)***.

From Baka-Updates:

> I reincarnated as an evil god.
>
> Ira Takuto succumbed to illness at a young age and ended up reincarnating in a world that resembled the strategy simulation game, 『Eternal Nations』, of which he loved playing when alive. What appeared in front of him was Atou, a girl belonging to the evil civilization that he used to play as, 「Mynoghra」. The two of them decided to create a new country in this world once again.

The protagonist, Ira Takuto, dies in bed from illness at the age of 18, and then suddenly finds himself sitting on a stone throne in a forest. It turns out that he's inside a country management simulation game called 'Eternal Nations', which he was the top-ranked player in before he died.

He's also greeted by a female hero called 'Atou', who addresses him as her king and master, and remembers everything they did 'together' when he played the game in the real world. In fact, she's keen for them to start the game over, and build a new country like they did before, and he agrees.

One of the first things they do is summon a 'scout unit', which resembles a giant ant, to scout the area around them. The scout unit discovers a settlement of dark elves nearby. It turns out that the elves are refugees from another land, where they'd been persecuted and chased out. They're also starving, so Ira uses his powers to conjure up food for them.

This last part isn't relevant to your description, but the elves also perceive Ira as a dark shadowy being, rather than the normal-looking person the reader sees him as. As a result of this perception, they're reluctant to trust him initially, but their leader feels forced to beg for his aid out of desperation.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is “[Survival in Another World with My Mistress!](https://sevenseasentertainment.com/series/survival-in-another-world-with-my-mistress-manga/)” (Goshujin-sama to Yuku Isekai Survival!).

While it is a cricket rather than an ant monster and she doesn’t save him, the two lead characters do sleep together and he uses his Minecraft-like abilities to save a refugee village and she is a former princess.

[image: cover]
[image: cricket monster]
[image: Minecraft cheats]